# AWS Authentication on Android with Facebook and Google

Tags: android, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am developing an Android application that needs access to certain specific AWS resources. A user should have the ability to sign up/in using Facebook, Google, or create a custom log in and the they should be given permissions to access specific sns queues and specific s3 folders depending on who they are.

Is there some way to configure AWS to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you will have to use a hybrid approach to achieve all of your requirements.  I suggest you take a look at the following two applications we have which show different pieces of what you are asking for:

- [S3 Personal File Store](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313) with [Web Identity Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingWIF.html) (avaialble on [GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_WIF_PersonalFileStore))
- [S3 Personal File Store](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) with [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4611615499399490)

While it is written on iOS, you may also be interested in a sample we prepared for re:Invent 2013 called [Mobile Photo Share](https://github.com/awslabs/reinvent2013-mobile-photo-share). If you want to learn more about the Mobile Photo Share app, we had two talks at re:Invent about the app and its architecture. The video and slides for those talks are available here:

- [Building Cloud-Backed Mobile Apps](http://bit.ly/1bPG0mx)
- [Integrating Social Login Into Mobile Apps](http://bit.ly/1fDgMP9)